# Loading animation for ASP.NET TreeView populated by Web Service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm very new to ASP.NET, and really know nothing about AJAX, but have been trying (unsucessfully) to find a reference online that would give me some usable code.

I have a TreeView that is populated by a Web Service.  The TreeView has to pull down a fairly large set of data to populate itself, so for a while the page is blank.  The page doesn't signal that it's loaded until that entire set of data is loaded, and whatever javascript I've tried to use doesn't get activated until everything's loaded.

I need to show a loading animation *while* things are loading, so I'm kind of in a catch-22.  I've tried to use `UpdatePanel`s and `UpdateProgress`, but these don't seem to do anything - at least not without some corresponding C# code.

If anyone can steer me towards a basic walkthrough of this (what I think should be) pretty simple/basic/common issue, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you make an ajax call where you need to show a "loading spinner", you need to show that little image BEFORE you make that AJAX call.

Then, within the AJAX callback, remove the spinner image and display the data instead.

That way, the image will be showing while the AJAX call is taking place.

Since you said you're new to all this, I suggest that you use jquery, as it's got all that simplified (compared to native-javascript approach).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you can load your page, then click a button to asynchonously load the TreeView (showing a loading image while it loads).  You can adapt the conepts to your needs =)

Put your `TreeView` in an `UpdatePanel`, but do not bind it to your datasource yet.  Also include a button to load the `TreeView` (just for the sake of the example) and set it as one of the `Triggers` for your `UpdatePanel`.  Like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click here to load the TreeView" onclick="Button1_Click" />

        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
            // TreeView details go here
        </asp:TreeView>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now, in the `Button1_Click`, you can bind your data to the `TreeView` by calling the web service:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is where you would bind the data to your TreeView using the web service
    TreeView1.DataSource = GetData();
}
```

This will cause just your `UpdatePanel` to reload with the `TreeView`.  Now you just need the javascript function that displays a loading image while you wait:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSpinner() {
        $("#<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>").append("<img id='spinnerImg' src='/Images/ajaxSpinner.gif' ></img>");
    }
</script>
```

Note: When the `UpdatePanel` finishes reloading, it will do so without the loading image (so there is no need to explicitly remove it).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what I needed to do based on this article:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delay-Load-Lazy-Load-UpdatePanel-using-Timer-Control-in-ASP.Net.aspx

As Jadarnal27 pointed out, part of it was a matter of seperating my loading of the treeview out to a separate function and calling that from within the updatepanel.

Now my only problem is that while this works perfectly on our test server, it's not working on our production one. All I see is a broken gif with no progress.  According to my colleague the only difference between the two servers is that the production one has .Net 1.1, 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0, whereas the testing one only has 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0.  He says he's seen this before where somewhere in the upgrade process things get messed up and the only way to fix them is to reinstall .net...

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider upvoting (with the grey up arrow) or accepting it =)

Comment: Regarding your new issue, is the image just not coming up, or does the whole UpdatePanel / async update process break on the production server?  Might be worth posting a separate question on that.